# How to warn about vue3 composition api if(ref<boolean>) comparisons

Tags: vuejs3, vue-composition-api

i am newly using vue3 composition api and found that a source of multiple errors over the past 2 days for me has been code like

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref} from "vue";

const show = ref<boolean>(false);
....

function someFunc():void{
 if(show){
 // do sth...
} 

</script>
```

Since `show` exists and in reality I want to compare to `show.value`. So this seems to be kind of errorprone to me. Maybe that gets better after using vue3 for a while but I wonder if there is some sort of linting rules to prevent such comparisons or also prevent sth like

```
if(boolean && show)
```

Thanks
Tom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for [`vue/no-ref-as-operand`](https://eslint.vuejs.org/rules/no-ref-as-operand.html).

> Disallow use of value wrapped by `ref()` (Composition API) as an operand

> This rule is included in all of `"plugin:vue/vue3-essential"`, `"plugin:vue/essential"`, `"plugin:vue/vue3-strongly-recommended"`, `"plugin:vue/strongly-recommended"`, `"plugin:vue/vue3-recommended"` and `"plugin:vue/recommended"`.

Install any of the above plugins and use them with `eslint`.

Produces the following error:

[image]

---

Side note: if you want to get rid of `.value` altogether, consider using `reactive()` (with an object) instead:

```js
const state = reactive({
  myRef: null
})

if (state.myRef) {
  // do something
}

// expose for template, so you can use `myRef` instead of `state.myRef`
const { myRef } = toRefs(state)
```

Might feel clunky with a single `ref()` but from 2 `ref()`s up it becomes more useful.
I also like the fact I get to pick and choose what's available on template's root level, as sometimes I put reactive props/computed on `state` which are only used in `setup`.